# Duplicate RxJS import warning

Tags: angular, typescript, migration, rxjs

I just upgraded from RxJS 5 to 6, and updated my code using the migration tool:

`rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p tsconfig.json`

At the end of the results, I got a series of messages like this:

> WARNING: /path/to/file.ts[3, 1]: duplicate RxJS import

As far as I can tell, this warning appears for every file in my project that imports more than one thing from rxjs (e.g. `import {Observable, BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs"`).  The [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#import-paths) has multiple imports as an example, so I would assume that should be fine.  A Google search only returned [one single result](https://books.google.com/books?id=fnteDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=warning+%22duplicate+rxjs+import%22&source=bl&ots=AkPxd833hZ&sig=p5XKix7PfpXGNxJZMuhsfEIL1Is&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDsJX2x9HbAhWRAnwKHYiYCHAQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=warning%20%22duplicate%20rxjs%20import%22&f=false) for the warning message, and it doesn't appear to address the same problem (none of the files have any deprecated imports).

What does it mean, and is it anything to worry about?

Answer (score 3):

Try re-running these commands. It should fix the problem.

```
npm i -g rxjs-tslint
npm i rxjs-tslint
rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json
```

Worst case you can add the compatibility package

```
npm i --save rxjs-compat
```